# Change logic at runtime

Tags: c++

The new Unreal Engine 4 is able to change the game logic at runtime. For example you can jump into the game, change some game logic and once it is recompiled it will be updated in the game itself.

I was wondering how they did it?

My first idea was that they separate their game logic to a .dll and then they are just reloading/injecting it at runtime. But I also know that .dlls are windows specific. I think the equivalent in linux is called .elf.

What alternatives are there?

I also know that there is a c++ interpreter available but I think the newer version uses a jit compiler now. Would this help me in any way?

I hope you can clear things up for me.

Comment: Game logic is generally scripted, so doesn't require compilation in the sense that you're imagining; if nothing else, it doesn't require _linking_ into the game process.

Comment: Ok according to Wikipedia UE4 supports "direct editing of C++ code". Yeah, I don't know, then.

Comment: Yes i know that I could use something like Lua or Python to achieve the same thing, but I am curious how they are doing it in c++.

Comment: Most likely, they have a DLL containing the game code separate from the engine application. When the game DLL is recompiled, they unload the current dll and load the new one in. Having an interpreter would defeat the purpose of C++. Linux and mac both have dynamic libraries just like DLLS (on mac dylib, on linux I think its an SO)

Comment: @JustinMeiners I don't know how viable the c++ interpreter is but the idea is that I could use the interpreter only for prototyping where performance isn't critical.

Comment: @MaikKlein think about templates alone.. C++ is not built for that.

Comment: Reads like marketing spin, the DLL is just reloaded in UE4:  "Make updates directly in game without ever pausing gameplay with Hot Reload. This tool allows you to quickly find and edit C++ code and see those changes reflected immediately in game."

Comment: @Steve-o perfect explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unreal Engine does this by using **Hot Reload** which basically (re)compiles the source code that has been changed and reloads it back into game. The game will be in a paused state while compilation is taking place.

[This presentation](http://www.bitsquid.se/presentations/cutting-the-pipe.pdf) goes into more detail about the technique.

Comment: Unreal Engine 4 probably only uses c++.